# Given some arbitrary roots of a polynomial p(x,y,z,...) with integer coefficients, is it possible to tell if p has a root in the Gaussian integers?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to find if p(x,y,z,...)=0 has a Gaussian integer root (more specifically, I want to find if p has a Gaussian integer root where the imaginary components are even, but if that can't be done, don't worry about it).

I can use the continuous Newton's Method to experimentally find complex roots of the polynomial, but I'd like to determine if a root of the sort I've specified exists without having to find more than just a few roots experimentally.

Unfortunately, I know absolutely 0 Galois Theory.  I'm aware that this is possible if the order of the polynomial is less than or equal to 4, but that's horribly limiting for my problem.  In general, the order of my polynomial will be pretty huge.

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction for solving this problem?

Edit:  Since my original problem is probably unsolvable:

My full problem is, given a root to a p(x,y,z,...) with integer coefficients, find whether or not p(x,y,z,...) = 1 (mod 2) using only reductions to be that can be done in polynomial time in the number of variables.

I suspect this problem, however, is simply too hard to solve as it is essentially SAT with a bit of extra information.

However, the reason I'm wondering if this is solvable is because it would imply that you can use differential equation solvers (such as analog electrical circuits) to solve hard computation problems.

Comment: For completely general polynomials this is known to be undecidable, so the problem can't be solved. However if you have specific polynomials in mind there may be a way for those.

Comment: @MattSamuel : do you mean that for a polynomial in 1 variable it is enough to factorize it approximately for proving none of the roots are integers, but for polynomials in several variables there is no such factorization in general  ?

Comment: @MattSamuel : Interesting.  Can you point me to any information on this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem

Comment: I don't have a proof that the same is true for Gaussian integers, but note that you can split it into two polynomial equations and look for integer solutions to find Gaussian integer solutions.

Comment: @user1952009 multivariable polynomials don't necessarily split into linear factors, and over the complex numbers they often have uncountably many roots.

Comment: @MattSamuel : OK, so that strongly suggests that my problem, as originally stated, is unsolvable.

As for further restrictions I can make on the polynomial:

My full problem is to see if knowing some roots (generally complex) to an integer coefficient polynomial speeds up finding if the polynomial mod 2 has any roots (SAT with a little extra information gotten from a differential equation solver).

I can make any polynomial time reduction to the polynomial.  For instance, I suspect it can be reduced to having all coefficients = 1.